# Equivalent ruby load function in python

Tags: python, ruby, python-3.x

`ruby` `load()` function load inside and entire `ruby` file in current file and run it.
load can get any string path: relative,static,...
what in equivalent function to do this in `python 3`?
have `python` equivalent function or not?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has the [`execfile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#execfile) which is similar, in that it will load and execute the file *each time*, unlike an imported module.

The `wrap` argument to the Ruby `load` function can be simulated by passing in a new namespace:

```
namespace = {}
execfile(filename, namespace)
```

Comment: thanks. what is diffrent between this and   
`loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("a", "/home/a.py")
loader.load_module()`

Comment: @unkhown: `importlib` returns a new module object, `execfile()` does not (it uses the current globals or a mapping you pass in as the namespace instead).

Comment: how i can prevent module to reload?. import do this automaticaly i think. when use importlib or execfile().

Comment: @unkhown: what is your goal here? To have the same functionality as `load` you'd want to see the file loaded each time. You can track what you loaded yourself in both Ruby and Python then. Otherwise just use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to dynamically import modules and have the normal import rules apply (including caching of previously imported modules).

Comment: sorry.its another question i say here.